# What is the best way to debug broken injection(due to minification)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I have project with "100500" services and when I switched on minification I got such kind of error:

```
__vendor.js?d7c479e…:41 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate modulemymodule due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module events due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
```

I'm using full notation everywhere, so

```
$inject = [...]
```

but it looks like in some places it's broken.
What would be the best way to localize the problem? (Not to check 100500 services one by one.)

Comment: You cannot use `$inject` everywhere, like in `run` or `config` blocks. Check those to use the array notation

Comment: thanks for feedback. ok, I'm using it everywhere except `run` and `config` blocks

Answer (score 2):

I found the way.
You need to switch minification OFF and turn **strictDi mode** ON. It will show you exact place with broken injection.

You can turn on strictDi in html with `ng-strict-di` directive:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
```

or with bootstrap option:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'], {
  strictDi: true
});
```